# How to Lookup values across multiple tables and Sum Value Column if Present?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a first table Kids brands on to which I want to sum search volumes of those brands on each of the row when a phrase containing that brand exists on my lookup table.

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|    Kids Brands     | Search Volume Sum |
+--------------------+-------------------+
| adidas             |                   |
| Ben Sherman        |                   |
| Calvin Klein       |                   |
| Calvin Klein Jeans |                   |
| Diesel             |                   |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I have the second lookup table with the following values

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|        Keyword        | Avg. monthly searches |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| adidas boys           |                  1000 |
| adidas for girls      |                  2900 |
| adidas kids           |                  5400 |
| alpha industries boys |                    20 |
| alpha industries kids |                    90 |
| ben sherman boys      |                    50 |
| ben sherman kids      |                   170 |
| boss boy              |                   390 |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

The final output should be

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|    Kids Brands     | Search Volume Sum |
+--------------------+-------------------+
| adidas             |              9300 |
| Ben Sherman        |               220 |
| Calvin Klein       |                 0 |
| Calvin Klein Jeans |                 0 |
| Diesel             |                 0 |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Can you please help with this.

Comment: SUMIFS allows wild cards: `=SUMIFS(table2[Search Volume Sum],table2[Kids Brands],table1[@[Kids Brands ]&"*")`

Comment: If the Keyword doesn't necessarily begin with the brand, you could add another wildcard before `table1[@[Kids Brands]`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Next time can you please let us know what have you tried when asking the question? I would suggest you to add a helper column in the Second look up table to identify the main brand for each sub-brand, and then use **SUMIF** to sum the total for each main brand in your first table. Using wild card in **SUMIFS** may not return the correct figure for **Calvin Klein** as it may include sales from **Calcin Klein Jeans**.